# How can I find the Thevenin Equivalent in a RC circuit with dependent current source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, thevenin

In the picture below, at time $t=0$ the switch closes and the voltage of the capacitor is 10 volt.

I am asked to find the Thevenin equivalent right from A,B terminals.But there is a dependent current source in the circuit.How can I proceed ? Any help ?

[image]

Comment: Well, the dependent source is just a resistor. You could replace it. Then the equivalent to the right is downright easy. Or do you want some other way to handle it?

Comment: @periblepsis is that possible to replace the dependent source with a resistor?With home many ohms?

Comment: Since you ask, I'll take a minute and show you how to see it. It's not always useful because situations vary and this is a unique kind of situation where that works. But having a flexible view (adaptable mental modes of observation) is a good thing to work for. So it's probably worth a moment. Hope it does help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May as well draw out the schematic and number the parts (something you should actually do to aide communication when posting a question):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx8ooq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To make what I'm about to say a little easier, I'm going to assign a ground to one of the wires (\$V_{\text{B}}=0\:\text{V}\$.) The other node is \$V_{\text{A}}\$ and is its value is to be understood to be in reference to that ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXRMiI.png)</sup>

The above two schematics are identical for all analysis purposes.

I'll do the math in a moment. But this is a good moment to just think about things.

What is the current in \$R_2\$? It's just a current source that depends on the applied voltage, \$V_{\text{A}}\$, by the factor \$\frac1{R_2}\$. But \$I_1\$ is tied between the same nodes (wires), isn't it? True, \$I_1\$ is \$7\times\$ larger. But that just means \$7\times\$ lower resistance. Not so? In short, isn't \$I_1\$ ***also*** a current source depending on the same voltage source, except that its current is \$7\times\$ more than in \$R_2\$?

A voltage controlled current source, controlled by the applied voltage across it, is just the same thing as a resistor. By definition, a resistor has the voltage dependent current of \$I_R=\frac{V_R}{R}=f\left(V_R\right)=\frac1{R}\cdot V_R\$. (A voltage dependent current source with the applied voltage being the controlling voltage.)

Anyway, that's a bunch of words to try and get you to think in a different mode for a moment. Let's go back to the math, now.

\$I_\Delta=f\left(V_{\text{A}}\right)=\frac1{R_2}\cdot V_{\text{A}}\$

and,

\$I_1=7\cdot I_\Delta=7\cdot f\left(V_{\text{A}}\right)=\frac7{R_2}\cdot V_{\text{A}}=\frac{V_\text{A}}{\left[\frac{R_2}{7}\right]}\$

So this would behave exactly the same as if we made up a new resistor, \$R_3=\frac{R_2}{7}\$. Not so? Then:

\$I_1=g\left(V_{\text{A}}\right)=7\cdot f\left(V_\text{A}\right)=\frac1{R_3}\cdot V_{\text{A}}\$

Yeah. That's a resistor behavior.

And now you can compute \$R_3\$'s value, too.

Given three resistors in parallel like this, I'm sure you can work out the equivalent circuit using only one resistor to replace them.

The KCL for just the right side would have been:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_2}+7\cdot I_\Delta&=0
\\\\
\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_2}+7\cdot\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_1}&=0
\\\\
\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{A}}{R_2}+\frac{V_\text{A}}{\frac{R_1}7}&=0
\end{align*}$$

How can it be otherwise that \$\frac{R_1}7\$ isn't just another resistance?

Comment: Wait a minute.Since there is only a dependent source the voltage of the open circuit and current of the short circuit will be 0.All I will get will be a resistor. If you connect to the terminals A,B a current source of 1A how can I proceed further? I find your approach interesting and mindful and I appreciate that but I want to keep things easy now because recently I started to get around electrical circuits.Can you update your answer with my approach?At the end I will have a RC circuit.I just need the Resistor equivalent.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Initial values! You wrote `at time $t=0$ the switch closes and the voltage of the capacitor is 10 volt.` Please take note of that fact. This is what gives the circuit its *start*. Does that make sense? Did I misunderstand you and I should read your words better than I did? I'd rather avoid using *your approach* as it requires me to read minds, doesn't it? All I can really do is show you one way that works well for me about how it could be approached. Differing people find differing ways individually better, though. We try to share our minds. All we can do. You pick then. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply a test voltage (\$V_X\$) source across A and B terminals.
And next, solve for \$I_X\$ (voltage source current).
And from there you can calculate the \$R_{TH} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = 10k\Omega||\frac{20k\Omega}{7 + 1}\$

Take a look at this example:

[image]

From KCL we have

$$I_X = \frac{V_X}{20k\Omega} + 7  \frac{V_X}{20k\Omega}$$
$$\frac{I_X}{V_X} = \frac{1}{20k\Omega} + \frac{7}{20k\Omega} = \frac{7 +1}{20k\Omega} $$
$$\frac{I_X}{V_X} = \frac{7 +1}{20k\Omega} $$

And the Thevenin resistance is equal to

$$R_{TH} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = \frac{20k\Omega}{7 + 1} = 2.5k\Omega$$

Comment: Useful way but say that I connect a voltage source in the terminals A,B then how I proceed?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson  I updated my answer.

Comment: Where the 10kΩ resistor has gone?

Comment: I split the problem. Notice that we have all components connected in a parallel manner. Thus, if we found equivalent resistance of a dependent source we can now include the 10k resistor in our circuit.